# Display descriptions on items only if applicable -- how to do it without several nested IF functions in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a scenario where I'd want a cell to display certain information depending on another set of "trigger" cells. It's a bit simpler if there are only two "trigger cells", i.e.:

```
*Trigger Cells:

Display description 1? (C1)   Yes
Display description 2? (C2)   No


Display Cell (A1) Formula = 
IF(AND(C1 = "Yes", C2 = "Yes), "Description 1" & "Description 2", IF(C1 = "Yes", "Description 1", IF(C2 = "Yes", "Description 2", "N/A"))))
```

This is done by looking at all the different combinations: both triggers are 'yes' ; only trigger 1 is 'yes'; only trigger 2 is 'yes' ; (with "value if false" making up the "both triggers are 'no' combination)

The issue is when I have more than 2 trigger cells, let's say 6 or more (with number of description = number of trigger cells). Aside from creating a convoluted IF statement that encompasses ALL the different combinations of Yes/No, is there a way to easily do this?

Thank you.

Comment: If both are "Yes", do you want to display "Both Descriptions" as your example suggests, OR do you want it to display "Description 1, Description 2"?

Comment: Description 1, Description 2. Sorry should have been more clear about that. Will edit the question.

Comment: You can look into `TEXTJOIN()`, depending on your Excel license. You can create an array formula looking for your YES/NO range and return the descriptions concatenated with a `, `.

Comment: That would have worked perfectly-- unfortunately I don't think my Excel has it. It is Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2016, but it doesn't recognize the TEXTJOIN function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CONCAT (or CONCATENATE for older Excel versions), with one IF after the other:

```
=CONCAT(IF(C1="Yes","Description 1,",""), IF(C2="Yes","Description 2,",""))
```

This may add extra comma's but I will leave you to work out how to clean that up.

To add an "N/A" in the case of no "Yes"s, you could wrap this formula in one more IF:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C1:C2,"Yes")=0,"N/A",
    CONCAT(IF(C1="Yes","Description 1,",""), IF(C2="Yes","Description 2,",""))
)
```

EDIT: A MORE COMPLEX SOLUTION

If you have multiple triggers, it may be neater to create a lookup table of all the possible results and then look it up using a code:

[image]

Convert the yes/no's to a series of ones and zeros (binary codes).

Then simply look up the code using INDEX MATCH.

This makes it very easy to update a result for a particular combination without combing through a really long formula.

Comment: Put the Commas at the **start**, and wrap the whole thing in `MID(<>, 2, 999)` to remove the first character?

Comment: @Chronocidal That would do it :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That does exactly what I need! There are multiple ways to 'clean it up', but that's a simple task. The complex solution is very neat and certainly the "smarter" way to go about it because I do have quite a bit of combinations. Thanks again :)!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CHOOSE` here, which also allows you to expand to more Description options:

```
C1 | C2 | Output
 N |  N | N/A
 Y |  N | Desc1
 N |  Y | Desc2
 Y |  Y | Desc1 & Desc2
```

Now, if we combine that into binary bits, then we can have `C1=Yes` as 00 or 01 (0 or 1 in Decimal) and `C2=Yes` as 00 or 10 (0 or 2 in Decimal), and add them together:

```
C1 | C2 | Output
 N |  N | 0 + 0 = 0
 Y |  N | 1 + 0 = 1
 N |  Y | 0 + 2 = 2
 Y |  Y | 1 + 2 = 3
```

Then add 1, because `CHOOSE` is 1-indexed:

```
=CHOOSE(1 + (C1="Yes") + 2*(C2 = "Yes"), "N/A", "Description 1", "Description 2", "Description 1" & "Description 2")
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll be testing it out right now. I'm assuming that this makes the formula a lot easier than several nested IF functions, however I would still have to map all the different combinations depending on the number of descriptions I have. i.e. if I have 2 descriptions, I need to map 4 combinations. 3 descriptions = 9 combinations, 5 = 125, etc.? I wanted to avoid mapping 125 different combinations as I do have cases with 5 descriptions, but I'm starting to think that it cannot be done simply.

Comment: @Tester_Y Gravitate has [posted a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56447702/9290986), which I *was* also going to include, but he posted it before I got that far, but which does not allow for the "N/A" (unless you have a big `AND` to check for that before concatenating strings)

Comment: Appreciate your input! Immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Although I always prefer non-VBA solutions, in this case emulating your own concatenate IF function (so we can test against criteria) is a good replacement for the `TEXTJOIN()` formula.

So taken from [here](http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=12298#) for example:

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, Condition As Variant, _
        ConcatenateRange As Range, Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strResult As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If CriteriaRange.Count <> ConcatenateRange.Count Then
        ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If
    For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
        If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
            strResult = strResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    If strResult <> "" Then
        strResult = Mid(strResult, Len(Separator) + 1)
    End If
    ConcatenateIf = strResult
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Call it like:

```
=ConcatenateIf(C1:C6,"yes",B1:B6)
```

Result:

[image]

There even is a ConcatenateIfs UDF for multiple conditions.

**EDIT:**

For future reference, might people have the appropriate Excel, the use of `TEXTJOIN()` can take care of this like so:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(C1:C6="yes",B1:B6,""))}
```

Comment: That is slick! Wish I could accept multiple answers. Definitely can add this as a module and essentially have that UDF available in my spreadsheets to replace the TEXTJOIN function. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries @Tester_Y.